# Pandas : How to find substring position in another column of the second DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, substring

I am trying to match products(Product2) in df2 with df1["Product1"] which can involve substring match.
Looking for the result

```
0    False
1    True 
2    True 
3    True
```

but I am getting all False. Where am I going wrong?

```
firstProductSet = {'Product1':['Computer','Phone','Printer','Desk'],'Price1':[1200,800,200,350]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(firstProductSet,columns= ['Product1', 'Price1'])
secondProductSet = {'Product2': ['PPP','Ph','Printer','Desk'],'Price2':[900,800,300,350]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(secondProductSet,columns= ['Product2', 'Price2'])
print(df2)`enter code here`

#add the Price2 column from df2 to df1

df1['productMatch?'] = np.where(df1['Product1'].str.find(str(df2['Product2'])) !=-1, 'True', 'False')  #create new column in df1 to check if prices match
print (df1)
```

Comment: Solved the problem yet?  Feel free to ask if you need further assistance.  Please share your solution if you have solved it another way.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem of Your Codes:

Your code doesn't work because Product1 and Product2 are in 2 different DataFrames and hence could not be iterated together in vectorized array operations. Passing `str(df2['Product2'])` to the str.find() function of the pandas Series of df1 most probably yields only the following string (scalar value) rather than the expected vectorized value of the same row index.

```
'0        PPP\n1         Ph\n2    Printer\n3       Desk\nName: Product2, dtype: object'
```

Hence, the str.find() produces no match.

### Solution not trivial:

To perform the vectorized operation, you have to combine the 2 dataframes into one and operate over the combined dataframe.  However, **a simple column concat over the 2 dataframes cannot achieve your task** for more generic data inputs. Let's explain this by an example.

E.g. if secondProductSet has Product2 with slightly different combinations ['Ph','Printer','Desk', 'PPP'], i.e.  **'PPP' placed at the end of list**.  Then the simple column concat will give:

```
   Product1  Price1 Product2  Price2  productMatch?
0  Computer    1200       Ph     800          False
1     Phone     800  Printer     300          False
2   Printer     200     Desk     350          False
3      Desk     350      PPP     900          False
```

Surely, this is not the result we want because there is actually some matching products in Product2 with Product1.  **The mismatch is resulted in when the 2 product sets are not aligning in sequence for matching products.**

### Cartesian Product or Cross Join Required in Solution:

To perform your tasks, you have to build a join giving 4 x 4 rows in an intermediate dataframe, perform the column-wise substring operation within each row, then consolidate the resulting matches.   Detailed steps as follows:

## **1. Cross Join df1, df2**

Cross join the 2 dataframes by the codes:

For pandas version >= 1.2.0 (December 26, 2020)

```
df_combined = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')     # how='cross' is new in pandas version 1.2.0
```

For pandas version < 1.2.0

```
df1['join'] = 1
df2['join'] = 1

df_combined = df1.merge(df2, on='join').drop('join', axis=1)
df2.drop('join', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Resulting dataframe df_combined (4 x 4 = 16 rows):

```
    Product1    Price1  Product2    Price2
0   Computer    1200    PPP         900
1   Computer    1200    Ph          800
2   Computer    1200    Printer     300
3   Computer    1200    Desk        350
4   Phone        800    PPP         900
5   Phone        800    Ph          800
6   Phone        800    Printer     300
7   Phone        800    Desk        350
8   Printer      200    PPP         900
9   Printer      200    Ph          800
10  Printer      200    Printer     300
11  Printer      200    Desk        350
12  Desk         350    PPP         900
13  Desk         350    Ph          800
14  Desk         350    Printer     300
15  Desk         350    Desk        350
```

## **2. Match substring in each row**

Match the substring in Product2 with Product1:

```
df_combined['productMatch?'] = df_combined.apply(lambda x: x.Product1.find(x.Product2), axis=1).ge(0)
```

`ge(0)` to test for return code of find() >= 0  [same result as your checking != -1 ]

[boolean values True, False returned instead of string 'True', 'False' in your code]

```
    Product1    Price1  Product2    Price2  productMatch?
0   Computer    1200    PPP         900             False
1   Computer    1200    Ph          800             False
2   Computer    1200    Printer     300             False
3   Computer    1200    Desk        350             False
4   Phone        800    PPP         900             False
5   Phone        800    Ph          800              True
6   Phone        800    Printer     300             False
7   Phone        800    Desk        350             False
8   Printer      200    PPP         900             False
9   Printer      200    Ph          800             False
10  Printer      200    Printer     300              True
11  Printer      200    Desk        350             False
12  Desk         350    PPP         900             False
13  Desk         350    Ph          800             False
14  Desk         350    Printer     300             False
15  Desk         350    Desk        350              True
```

## **3. Consolidate resulting Matches**

a) Group the matching results above by the original columns of df1.
b) Use max() on groupby object to get the max of column 'match' (True is 1, False is 0, hence max() gives True if there is any True within the same Product1 item).

```
df_result = df_combined.groupby(['Product1', 'Price1'], sort=False).max().reset_index()[['Product1', 'Price1','productMatch?']]
```

Result:

```
    Product1    Price1  productMatch?
0   Computer    1200            False
1   Phone        800             True
2   Printer      200             True
3   Desk         350             True
```